# Allocate memory request and limit for the pods that airflow will create to run tasks in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I have deployed airflow with helm stable/airflow: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/airflow

I have deployed it with celery executor and I have run a task that need to read a big table. I am getting this error in the Pod that run this task:

```
The node was low on resource: memory. Container base was using 3642536Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.
I understand that I have exceed the memory of the node is running this pod.
```

I want to modify the limit of the memory and cpu each pod use in airflow. I can see that I can limit the resources of the workers.

My question is:

How can I specify the memory requests, the limit for the pods that are going to be created from the worker? Because I can only see how to set the resources from the workers but not the Pots that the workers create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be conflating the Celery Executor with the [Kubernetes Executor](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.1/kubernetes.html).  The Kubernetes Executor creates a new pod for every task instance.  With the Celery Executor you will get a preset number of worker pods to run your tasks.  For example, you would set the number of workers in advance [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/airflow/values.yaml#L543).  In which case, setting [these values](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/airflow/values.yaml#L523-L536) should give your worker pods the resources you require.  Their README has good example of how you can leverage dynamic scaling if that's what you're after.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify resources for scheduler by modifying [`values.yaml`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/airflow/values.yaml#L161) in the helm chart.

You can do it by pulling the chart locally, by running for example:

```
helm fetch --untar stable/airflow
```

Then modify `values.yaml` file in `scheduler:resources`, example:

```
 163 scheduler:
 164   resources:
 165      requests:
 166        cpu: "100m"
 167        memory: "1Gi"
 168      limits:
 169        cpu: "100m"
 170        memory: "1Gi"
```

and then install the chart `helm install airflow .` Specified resources will be assigned to the pods.

Comment: The scheduler resources are not to specify the scheduler pod? This resources specification are going to work also for the pods that are going to be created by the worker?